# Create class object instance named from string?

Tags: python, object, dynamic

I can't find the answer anywhere.

I have a class called "vrf".

I have an input file.

As Python iterates through the lines of this input file, every time it sees the word vrf, I want to create an object named after the next word.

So if it reading the line "ip vrf TESTER",
I would like to dynamically create an object named TESTER of type vrf.

```
TESTER = vrf()
```

How in the world do I do this?

I've tried:

```
line.split()[2] = vrf()
```

Doesn't work.

Comment: why don't you just use a dictionary?

Comment: A hack is to do `globals()[line.split()[2]] = vrf()`, but the dict solution is better, as it is not sane to modify `globals` (or `locals`) directly.

Comment: Suggested reading: [_Why you don't want to dynamically create variables_](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html) and [_Keep data out of your variable names_](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html). To which I would add "Keep language tags out of your question's title."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, dynamically created variable names are a bad idea. Instead, you should create a dictionary where the name is the key and the instance is the value

In your case it would look something like this:

```
objects = {}
...
object_name = line.split()[2]
objects[object_name] = vrf()
```

Then you can access it this way for your example:
    objects["TESTER"]
will give you the corresponding vrf instance.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use a dictionary?

```
object = {}
object[line.split()[2]] = vrf()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `globals()` dictionary can be edited to do this:

```
>>> globals()['TEST'] = vrf()
>>> type(TEST)
# <class 'vrf'>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is not a great idea, instead use a **dictionary**, or if your object has an instance variable that stores name information such as `name`, bind the data there.

```
objs = {}
objs[line.split()[2]] = vrf()
```

or (*if available*)

`v = vrf(line.split()[2])`

`v = vrf(); v.name = line.split()[2]`

Sample output:

```
print objs
>>> {'vrf' :  <__main__.vrf instance at 0x7f41b4140a28>}
```